# Gibbs within Metropolis

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

Consider a model with two parameters, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We want to sample these two parameters conditioning on two data points, $d_1$ and $d_2$. Is it possible to use an algorithm like this:

1) Sample from $P(\alpha \mid \beta, d_1)$

2) Sample from $P(\beta \mid \alpha, d_1)$

3) Apply some correction

4) Sample from $P(\alpha \mid \beta, d_2)$

5) Sample from $P(\beta \mid \alpha, d_2)$

6) Apply some correction

Basically, is it possible to break the data up into two sets, and use Gibbs sampling for each set, and then combine them somehow? Can anyone provide references to literature for how to do something like this?

The motivation is that for time series models, the first data point is special, because we assume that it comes from the equilibrium distribution, while all other data points are conditioned on the previous point. Since each parameter alters the equilibrium distribution, from a programming perspective, it would be much easier to be able to deal with calculating and adjusting for the equilibrium distribution in a single step instead of for each parameter.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question.

Comment: Could you explain the motivation a little more?  Do you want something that is easier to implement than standard Gibbs?  Or should it run faster (with reduced accuracy)?